# can't move file to directory in docker centos

Tags: docker, centos

I create a folder several month ago for moving file from vm machine to docker container,it work well,but now i can't use `docker cp` command to move it.so i copy the file to `/root`,it can work,but i still can't move it to the target directory,while i use command `mv` or `cp`,it will return this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfz2r.png)

I can copy the files which in `hadoop-jars/` to other directory,so I guess it has something wrong with the directory，by the way,I'm also wondering why some of my `.jar` files are red color but others are green.

Comment: When you perform 'docker copy', what message do you have? Does your copy look like this : docker cp ./test.jar 3e92567259:/root/hadoop-jars? (the container id may have changed if you restarted it in the meantime). How do you run your container (docker-compose? docker run?). When you do a 'docker inspect <id>' on your running container, what do you have under "Mounts" ?

Comment: It could be something to do with permissions for the `/root/hadoop-jars/` directory. Can you add the output of `ls -l /root` and `ls -l /root/hadoop-jars`.

Comment: yes i use `docker cp` like your mentioned; the container is running all the time, i run `docker exec -it` when i use it, the container id was not changed; i create the container by use `docker create`,run it by `docker start` and `docker exec`. `docker inspect` show nothing but an `[],`(it's empty) under 'Mounts' @Marvin

Comment: it shows `drwxr-xr-x` at `hadoop-jars` dir and `-rw-------` at the files in `hadoop-jars` dir @farhan3